# how to get session().getAttribute() from Servlet doGet in JSP with Struts

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

I cannot get the session Attribute from Servlet to JSP page.
My Servlet:(columnChartServlet.java)

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("myname", "Steve");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("age", "50");
}
```

My JSP (admin.jsp)

```
<head>
<%@page import="com.cos.sms.actions.columnChartServlet" %>
<jsp:useBean id="chartMast" class="com.cos.sms.actions.columnChartServlet" scope="session" />
</head>
<body>
<%= request.getAttribute("myname") %>
<%= request.getAttribute("age")  %>
<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("myname") %>
<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("age") %>

</body>
```

my Struts-config

```
<action input="/jsp/login.jsp" path="/login" name="loginForm"  type="com.cos.sms.actions.LoginAction" scope="session" parameter="method" >
    <forward name="admin" path="/jsp/admin.jsp"/>   
    <forward name="normal" path="/view_info.do?method=getDropdownSelectData"/>
    <forward name="diplayloginjsp" path="/jsp/login.jsp"/>
</action>
```

after logged in my admin.jsp will open in the url of login.do.

my web.xml config for servlet

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>columnChartServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.cos.sms.actions.columnChartServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>columnChartServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/columnChartServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

when i run application admin.jsp shows the print value as null.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you think you're doing. `useBean` instantiates a class and puts it into the specified scope--it doesn't magically run a servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will be able to retrieve data if you use like below in jsp

> session.getAttribute("myname");

and in your servlet try to use like below:

> request.getSession(false).setAttribute("myname", "Steve");

Comment: i used like that... but i didnt get any data, just null only...

Comment: may be did not create session for your application, thats why you are not getting data. i am updating the post

Comment: no, session is creating... i can able to retrieve data's of login details from session. like username, type, and all only this servlet data i cant able to read.

Comment: try the modified post

Comment: still no luck with modified post. still same null. is it correct the way calling servlet into jsp?

Comment: by the way use this in jsp, and lets see what happened session.getAttribute("myname");

Comment: still same, sir. passing null only... with just session.getAttribute("myname");